# How to fix this javascript memory leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

Following code example will create memory leak ( Detachted Dom Elements ). You can verify that by creating memroy profile in chrome dev tools.

Question : How to fix this issue.

I would like to know other scenarios where one can create detached DOM elements and possible fixes and things to avoid.

Following code example was taken from https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling-dom-leaks

```
    function start()
{
  var p = document.getElementById("p");
  detached = document.createElement("div");
  p.appendChild(detached);
  p.removeChild(detached);
  fill();
}

function fill()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.data = new Array(10000);
    for (var j = 0, l = div.data.length; j < l; ++j)
      div.data[j] = j.toString();
    detached.appendChild(div);
  }
}
```

Comment: How about a simple `detached = null`? Or fix the mistake by adding a `var` to `detatched = …;` to get an exception where you deserve it? Don't forget that this code is useless, it just serves as a trivial example that generates a lot of data on detached DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. Yea i understand that, this is just an example code but the problem is almost 95% of the examples on youtube or over the internet i saw was related to how to find the performance issue, but those examples are not focusing on how to fix it. To me it is kind of easy to find out if there is a peformance problem or not, but once i know that there is a problem "How to fix it" thats where i am struggling and i need more information on that.

Comment: The solution is always the same: drop the reference(s) that retain that data that should have been garbage-collected.